# filter one column by two conditions (one value and empty cell) in R

Tags: r

I'd like to filter a column wherein value is 0 or value has no data. I've tried the following lines but neither seems to be doing what I want.

```
# demo2122 = dataframe 
# grp_mlk = column 

demo2122 %>% filter(grp_mlk == 0 | grp_mlk == "")
demo2122 %>% filter(grp_mlk == 0 | grp_mlk == NA)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you tried `NA_integer_`? Other variations of NA? What type is the column? If this doesn't help, sharing a `dput(head(df))` would be illustrative.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `grp_mlk == NA`, use `is.na(grp_mlk)` as by default `filter` removes the `NA` rows

```
library(dplyr)
demo2122 %>%
    filter(grp_mlk == 0| is.na(grp_mlk))
```